# How to update values in an array for a chart using chartsJS and Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, charts

I'm trying to update a specific value in a data array for a chart using chartsJS and angular.
Specifically in this code I'm trying to update the first data point to a 0 when the "update data" button is clicked.
But even when specifying the correct elements in the array i keep getting the error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`.

I've tried using the push and pop methods but they only remove and add different data, but I want to replace it.

html code:

```
<button (click)="add()">Add Data</button>
```

chart set up code:

```
    this.NewChart = new Chart('totalJourneys', {
      type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Jan", 'Feb', "Mar", "Apr", "May","Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Number of Items Sold",
        data: [9,7,3,5,2,10,15,16,19,3,1,9],
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.2,
        backgroundColor: "light-blue",
      }]
    },
  });
```

Update chart function:

```
  public add() {
    console.log('added');
    this.NewChart.data.datasets.data[1].data[0] = 10;
    this.NewChart.update();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.NewChart.data.datasets[0].data[0] = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I also realised that I could declare the array separately and update it like that before I noticed I had an extra .data[].

Comment: No problem, if it answers your question, please mark it as so.